# Prevent standard action when you select [CSS, JS, android]

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, android-webview

I have made an app in android webview and I want that something can be copied. So when you press a button you will have something copied to your clipboard. 
I have tried ["clipboard.js"](https://clipboardjs.com/) works browers but not on android. So I used this javascript:

```
var copyXBT = function () {
var theTheCopyXBTAdr = $('#theToCopyXBT');
theTheCopyXBTAdr.select();
try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
}
```

};

But when you pressed the input type text will get a blue color,.. and blue border(android webview yellow) and on android your keyboard will pop up.

I use this css styling to "hide" it. Because I can't say display none. If I do that I won't work.

```
#theToCopyETH{
color: white;
border: 0px solid white;
}

::selection{
    background: white;
    color: white;
}
```

This is a piece of my HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-coinchecker" id="copyETH">Copy ETH address</button><button class="btn btn-coinchecker" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showETHQR">Click me to get the QR-code</button>
        <input type="text" id="theToCopyETH" value="*********************">
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8bvrwq0v/) for example (please open in Google Chrome)

So my question is how to prevent the pop-up of the keyboard and get rid of the yellow-border in android (google chrome on desktop is that blue)

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

What do I need to do to hide my keyboard is this js:

```
enter var hidekeyboard = function (e) {
    e.attr('readonly', 'readonly'); // Force keyboard to hide on input field.
    e.attr('disabled', 'true'); // Force keyboard to hide on textarea field.
    setTimeout(function() {
        e.blur();  //actually close the keyboard
        // Remove readonly attribute after keyboard is hidden.
        e.removeAttr('readonly');
        e.removeAttr('disabled');
    }, 100)
};
```

I need to add that after my selection has happend otherwise I won't work.
My copyETH looks like this then:

```
var copyETH = function () {
var theTheCopyETHAdr = $('#theToCopyETH');
theTheCopyETHAdr.removeClass('toggleDisplay');
theTheCopyETHAdr.select();
try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
}
hidekeyboard(theTheCopyETHAdr);
theTheCopyETHAdr.addClass('toggleDisplay');
};
```

So you can see I do also a removeClass and addClass. Because If I only use the hidekeyboard you can see the selection but with his css class it's gone + no-one can change the input field.

Here to see the solved [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h66kxtyg/)

Answer (score -1):

This should be enough to hide the input and prevent any activity when it's clicked/tapped, but not break your JS:

```
#theToCopyETH {
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: visibility: hidden; acts the same like display none; and pointer-events does nothing but thanks!